# Mac OS X Find Version returns two statements

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I've been writing a program and so far I think I'm doing pretty well. I have a function that finds the version of Mac OS X using platform.mac_ver(). I isolated the extra values from platform.mac_ver() so that it only includes the version and that's it. However, I want to add the flavour text with it as well. This is what I have:

```
def Version_Finder():
try:
    v, _, _ = platform.mac_ver()
    v = float('.'.join(v.split('.'[:2]))
    if v == 10.5:
        print("Mac OS X v. 10.5 Leopard")
    if v == 10.6:
        print("Mac OS X v. 10.6 Snow Leopard")
```

and so on until:

```
    if v == 10.10:
        print("Mac OS X v. 10.10 Yosemite")
    else:
        print("Mac OS X v. ", v)
```

and this is the output when I am running 10.9 Mavericks:

```
Mac OS X v. 10.9 Mavericks
('Mac OS X v. ', 10.9)
```

All I want is the first line of output but I think I need the else statement so that if someone is running something like 10.4 Tiger then they will still get the "Mac OS X v." part.

If you guys can help me, that would be great. :)

Comment: why cast as a float and not just compare strings? Also considering you are using a function you could return the values then that would solve your problem

Comment: Is the `try` statement included in the function `def Version_Finder():`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `elif` if you only want one part to run:

```
if v == ...
    pass
elif v == ...
    pass
elif v == ...
    pass
else:
    ...
```

Otherwise, you'll always get two text messages printed (as you've seen). The reason this happens it that in the following if/else, there's always one that's true:

```
if v == 10.10:
    print("Mac OS X v. 10.10 Yosemite")
else:
    print("Mac OS X v. ", v)
```

So if you're running 10.9 then it'll print for the `if v == 10.9` statement but it'll also check the above if/else statement. In that case the `if v == 10.10` is not true so it'll run the `else` part. And that means it'll print another text message.

Comment: Awesome! That just seemed to do the trick. I know that I am new to Python but I am guessing that elif is like "else if:" or something like that. But it worked! Thank's so much!